# How to sign my HTML document digitally in Django application

Tags: python, django, docusignapi, digital-signature

In my Django application I have a html file and it should get signed digitally.
When a client clicks on a link my html document should open in that tab and highlighting the signing area, then the client click on that portion a popup with text box to enter signature name and select font style or else he can upload his sign image.

Can anyone suggest me a better approach to achieve this? I integrated DocuSign API with my Django application. This DocuSign is accepting only pdf documents but I need to get signature on HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign eSignature REST API also accepts HTML documents. They are converted to PDF format for you.

If you have trouble supplying an HTML document to DocuSign, then please open a new question on StackOverflow and include the relevant parts of your code. Or include the JSON that was sent to DocuSign via the DocuSign request logging feature.